# How to perform chaining in sequelize association?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Suppose i have 3 models.

### Model 1: (author)

hasMany: books

### Model 2: (book)

belongsTo: author

hasOne: category

foreign key: authorId

### Model 3: (category)

belongsTo: book

foreign key: bookId

Now if i do,

```
author.findOne(where: {id: 1}, include: "books")
//then for author having id 1 i get all respective books
```

But i want the category as well for all the books. So is there any way i can chain further the book model to get the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Sequelize v6, you can perform a [nested eager loading](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/#nested-eager-loading) as follows:

```
author.findOne({
  where: {id: 1},
  include: {
    model: Book,
    include: {
      model: Category
    }
  }
})
```

Note that `Book` and `Category` are model instances.